# django with sqlite unable to open database file

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have sqlite database setting like in my production server :

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
```

}

I have also tried `chown www-data path_to_db` and `chmod 777 path_to_db`

I am using celery, rabbitmq and supervisor in this application.. 
but its still showing error saying unable to open database.. whats the issue here

Comment: Why aren't you using a proper database server in production?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Its a very small website so I used sqlite.. What might be the issue here ?

Comment: Are you sure, that `DATABASES.default.NAME` points to the correct location? How are you deploying your project?

Comment: I have did syncdb and created superuser too.. When I tried to login admin it said unable to write readonly database but after doing chown www-data path_to_db it gives unable to oepen database file error

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am also using celery, rabbitmq and supervisor .. but I am using all this in my local too and it worked fine with sqlite

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
chown www-data path_to_directory_containing_db
```

Answer (score 0):

First lets find out the value of BASE_DIR. Add to your settings.py

```
print "base dir %s" % BASE_DIR
```

And run server. You'll see your base_dir and could ensure that file is in right place.